# Next.js treating pages/API route as a client component?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a simple API route, `src/pages/api/me.ts` that simply echoes if the user is logged in or not.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { getSession } from '../../lib/session'

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    let user = getSession();
    res.status(200).end((user) ? 'yes' : 'no')
}
```

The import, `../../lib/session` (`src/lib/session.ts):

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export const getSession = () => {
    const nxtCookies = cookies();

    if (nxtCookies.has('wp_session')) {
        const cookie = nxtCookies.get('wp_session');

        // prints on the server
        console.log('this is happening on the server')

        let sessionData = jwt.verify(cookie.value, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return false;
            return user;
        });

        if (sessionData) return sessionData;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I try to call `getSession()` from `pages/api/me.ts`, I get an error:

> ./src/lib/session.ts
>
> You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works
> in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use
> client", so it's a Client Component.
>
> import { cookies } from 'next/headers';    :
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> One of these is marked as a client entry with "use client":
> src\lib\session.ts   src\pages\api\me.ts

How is this possible? Both are server-sided code.

I even have a server component that uses `getSession()` to display user information on the website, and this error is not thrown. I even verified via `console.log` that within both that component and `getSession()`, that the console prints to the server console. So I am not sure how this is possible.

Specifically, the issue here seems to be the `cookie` import from `next/headers`.

Comment: I just realized, I am running Next.js 13. In Next.js 13, the `app` directory is used, but the `api` route functionality from Next.js 12 was preserved. Even though I'm importing `next/headers`, maybe under the hood it's calling a different import (`src/app/session.ts` vs `src/pages/api/me.ts`)?

Comment: Nvm, my prior comment is not the case. I used `console.log(require.resolve('next/headers'))` in both files and they pointed to the same path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [cookies](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cookies) from `next/headers` is **only** for use in server components. `src/pages/api/me.ts`
is on the server but is not a server *component*.

You can access the cookies from a request through [`req.cookies`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers), and pass it to your `getSession` function.

A possible implementation of this would be:

```
// src/pages/api/me.ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getSession } from '../../lib/session'

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const user = getSession(req.cookies);
  res.status(200).end((user) ? 'yes' : 'no');
}
```

```
// src/lib/session.ts
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const getSession = (cookies: Partial<Record<string, string>>) => {
  const session = cookies.wp_session;

  if (session) {
    // prints on the server
    console.log('this is happening on the server');

    const sessionData = jwt.verify(session, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return false;
      return user;
    });

    return sessionData;
  }
}
```